# The "SELECT...IN..." operator is not working

Tags: cassandra, composite-key

With cassandra-1.1.2.
The Schema like this.

```
    CREATE TABLE contacts (
      userid text,
      contactid text,
      groups text,
      name text,
      PRIMARY KEY (userid, contactid)
    )
```

All the date it contains.

```
    cqlsh:contactks> select * from contacts;
     userid | contactid | groups | name
    --------+-----------+--------+------
          a |       a11 |    a13 |  a12
          a |       a21 |    a23 |  a22
          a |       a31 |    a33 |  a32
          b |       b11 |    b13 |  b12
```

so I make a query like this:

```
    cqlsh:contactks> select * from contacts where contactid in ('a11', 'a21');
    cqlsh:contactks>
```

Returns nothing!!!
How can I get values with the "IN" option without make the "contactid" as a partition key?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, I use the cassandra-1.1.2 as thd database .

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to implement a [secondary index](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/cql/SELECT#cql-select) on `contactid` in order for it to be searchable in the where clause.

Comment: but I can't execute "CREATE INDEX ON contacts(contactid);"  for "Bad Request: Secondary indexes are not (yet) supported on tables with composite PRIMARY KEY"

Comment: @user1600104 I think this is a known issue. See http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201206.mbox/%3CCAD4ZjiGDFBxNcT2HoCtG8ezy9rHY3q9fKuXQ7b5dKh4esJ=Edw@mail.gmail.com%3E and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3680

Comment: So I have to create the table with one primary key...and create an index on the "contactid"